# Separators and word postioning in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, cells, separator, language-translation

What excel vba code could invert the position of two words in a cell if they are separated by a space, like this:

```
"Broom eletric"
```

to

```
"Eletric broom"
```

And not to separate words when they are separated by "," like this:

```
"Broom, eletric" '(this one remains as it is)
```

And if there are lots of words in a cell, it will apply the rules to them all, like this:

```
"Broom eletric, eraser, documents,  part computer"
```

to

```
"Eletric broom, eraser, documents, computer part"
```

Plus: the separators should be "," and "and"

Comment: Your question is unclear in view of your last line.  However, Regular Expressions would probably be the easiest way to go.  If you clarify your problem, and  post your code and associated problems, some one will be happy to help you.  Also, please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes, you can do it by first counting the number of times comma (",") appears plus 1, it will be the number of set of words you need to swap.

Afterward, just split the original string into smaller parts by delimiter "," and swap each set, put them together again and you're done.

I can give you the algorithm and whatsnot, but without seeing the actual codes, I guess you want someone else to ... write it for you?

Comment: Truth is I didn't even knew where to begin, I just wanted to know if it was possible first, I will try to learn the things you said and post the codes once I have it.